# update string from a dictionary with the values from matching keys

Tags: python, string, dictionary, indexing

```
def endcode(msg,secret_d):
    for ch in msg:
        for key,value in secret_d:
             if ch == key:
                 msg[ch] = value
    return msg
encode('CAN YOU READ THIS',{'A':'4','E':'3','T':'7','I':'1','S':'5'})
```

This is my code. What I am trying to do here is for every characters in a string `msg`, the function should search in the dictionary and replace it with the mapping string if the character `ch` is a key in the dictionary `secret_d`.

If `ch` is not a key in `secret_d` than keep it unchanged.

For the example, the final result is should be `'C4N YOU R34D 7H15'`

Comment: Hey OP, have you come any further with the help of the answers you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function name is `endcode` but you are calling `encode`.

But more important, I'll give you a hint to what's going on. This isn't going to totally work, but it's going to get you back on track.

```
def endcode(msg,secret_d):
    newstr=""
    for ch in msg:
        for key,value in secret_d.iteritems():
            if ch == key:
                newstr=newstr+value
    print(msg)
endcode('CAN YOU READ THIS',{'A':'4','E':'3','T':'7','I':'1','S':'5'})
```

But if you want a complete answer, [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+endcode(msg,secret_d%29%3A%0A++++newstr%3D%22%22%0A++++for+ch+in+msg%3A%0A++++++++for+key,value+in+secret_d.iteritems(%29%3A%0A++++++++++++if+ch+%3D%3D+key%3A%0A++++++++++++++++newstr%3Dnewstr%2Bvalue%0A++++++++if(ch+not+in+secret_d%29%3A%0A++++++++++++newstr%3Dnewstr%2Bch%0A++++print(newstr%29%0Aendcode('CAN+YOU+READ+THIS',%7B'A'%3A'4','E'%3A'3','T'%3A'7','I'%3A'1','S'%3A'5'%7D%29+&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=5) is mine.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- As rb612 pointed out, there's a typo in your function definition ("en**d**code")
- you are doing nothing with the return value of your function after calling it
- `msg[ch]` is trying to assign items in a string, but that's not possible, strings are immutable. You'll have to build a new string. You cannot "update" it.
- in order to iterate over `(key, value)` pairs of a dictionary `d`, you must iterate over `d.items()`. Iterating over `d` will iterate over the keys only.

That being said, here's my suggestion how to write this:

```
>>> def encode(msg, replacers):
...     return ''.join([replacers.get(c, c) for c in msg])
... 
>>> result = encode('CAN YOU READ THIS',{'A':'4','E':'3','T':'7','I':'1','S':'5'})
>>> result
'C4N YOU R34D 7H15'
```

Things to note:

- `dict.get` can be called with a fallback value as the second argument. I'm telling it to just return the current character if it cannot be found within the dictionary.
- I'm using a list comprehension as the argument for `str.join` instead of a generator expression for performance reasons, here's an [excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024).

Comment: This is definitely a good answer. Mine (now edited) will do the same but overall not nearly as clean and compact.